# Are there human beatbox inspired conlangs?

Tags: list-of-languages, unnatural-features

[Human beatbox](https://www.humanbeatbox.com/) is an art form producing percussion sounds with the mouth only. It uses techniques and sounds that are rare or entirely absent in natural languages.

Are the constructed languages that take inspiration by human beatbox sounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to find conlangs based on such sounds but could not find any. However, the closest human phonemes to such sounds are clicks and many conlangs use them. I don't know any well-known conlangs that use clicks, but HyPry and Gdili were two that I could find.

You could try making one yourself, but given that Beatbox sounds are fairly limited and sometimes hard to distinguish, I doubt you would be able to make an effective language from it without adding in typical consonants and vowels.

Comment: Note that ejective plosives can also be counted as "beatbox phonemes", and they are significantly more common than clicks. Still too few to make a language though.

Comment: @Richard Very true. Forgot about those. If the OP combined clicks and ejective plosives with a few vowels, a functional sound system could start to take shape. Not sure how difficult pronunciation would be though.

Answer (score 1):

ANADEW: [Nuxalk (also known as Bella Coola)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuxalk_language#Syllables), a natural language of the Salishan family spoken at the west coast of Canada, has some beat-box elements: long strings of consonants without intervening vowels. Nuxalk features ejective consonants, too.

Comment: I was going to say this too! Great language :)