# Syllabic plosives

Tags: conlang-creation, naturalism, phonetics

Fricatives and Sonorants can be in a nucleus of a syllable. Can plosives also act as a syllable? If so, do any of your conlangs have this feature?

Answer (score 1):

ANADEW: [Nuxalk aka Bella Coola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuxalk_language#Syllables) is a natural language famous for its long chains of plosives. However, calling the plosives *syllables* in this case raises another question: Is syllable a term that is suitable for the description of Nuxalk, or should one say that there are no well-defined syllables in Nuxalk (see [this question on the linguistics stackexchange](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/29230/9781) for more on this).

For use in conlangs, see also [Are there human beatbox inspired conlangs?](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/q/771/142) on this site, five years ago there was kind of a "no" answer to the second question.